# serve_site loads core R libraries, build_site doesn't in blogdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

I use `blogdown` to generate a static blog. When I'm drafting, I use `serve_site()` to preview the output. This works fine.

However, I use `build_site()` in my makefile to publish the final version to the web. Posts that compile successfully with `serve_site` fail when they use functions in the `graphics()`, `utils()` or other base libraries. I can solve the problem by explicitly loading the required libraries in my posts.

I don't understand the difference between `serve_site` and `build_site` here - I think `serve_site` calls `build_site` itself. Is there a way to automate building a blogdown site from a script without having to explicitly load base libraries?

I'm working in Emacs/ESS, and I have the following Makefile for the blog:

```
publish: build
    rsync -vr public/ user@host:/var/www/html/

build:
    ./BuildBlog.r
```

`BuildBlog.r` is:

```
#!/home/tws/bin/r
library(blogdown)
blogdown::build_site()
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [package description](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/blogdown/blogdown.pdf) it looks like...
`build_site() - Compile all Rmd files and build the site through Hugo.`

while

`server_site() - The function serve_site()calls servr::httw()to start a web server, watch for changes in the site, rebuild the site if necessary, and refresh the web page automatically by default;stop_server()stops the web server.`

So build_site() renders the Rmd into HTML, and then server_site() hosts them with a web server service.

I have used them in the past, but asking what is the difference between them makes me wonder too. From my experience, I would use server_site() when making little changes, and then to re-render the entire directory I do build_site()

as for your question about building. I am not sure why those base libraries aren't loading initially. What functions are you using? sometimes if the function exist in OTHER libraries, it's best to just call the function with it's original library like `graphics::barplot()`

Comment: the problem is definitely with the base libraries. I have to load the libraries explicitly just to use fundamental functions like `par` and `data`, which aren't present in any other packages I use

Comment: What's the error it gives you? just that that function isn't available until you load it?

Comment: Yes, just that: could not find function "par"

Comment: another example I just ran into: 'Error in screeplot(spca2A) : could not find function "screeplot"'. `screeplot` is in the base package stats, and the problem disappears by adding `library(stats)` to my Rmd file.

Comment: Since you are building the site from a script, maybe you have to load the required base libraries. I use RStudio, but since you’re scripting it, I wonder if it needs more explicit instructions. Apologize I can’t be anymore of value you to you